# TFS: Statuses for solution & projects invalid after moving folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

OK, so one or more of the references required that the solution be in C drive. I cut-pasted the solution from one folder in D drive to another in C, and *bam*, all TFS bindings went down the drain.

I've changed my workspace local folder to point to my new folder, so I'm not sure why TFS doesn't recognize it. OK, I admit I was working without TFS connection for a period of time, but now I would like to get some changes checked in. But when I go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control, it tells me that the *Status* for my .sln and .proj files are all **Invalid**.

I've tried unbinding and rebinding projects but this doesn't seem to work.

This is frustrating. Is there any other way than to delete and re-download the entire solution? Or is this a caveat of TFS, is there any file on my hard drive that defines my solution location? It's 10GB worth, I don't want to need to do this every time I move my solution, especially when I actually have all the files on my hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you had your sources connected to TFS on your D: drive. For some strange reason you needed to move them to C: drive and you did this by using Windows Explorer (or any other not TFS related tool)? After that you changed your code and now want to check it in to TFS, but it denies it. Right?

The problem is that TFS didn't got any information about your moving and changes you made in the new location. This only works if you used "local workspace" setting when creating the workspace or if you changed your workspace to the new location and checked out the files there.

How I would "fix" this:

1. Copy/save your current code changes in a temp folder
2. Open VS/TeamExplorer and create/change your workspace to the location where you want your sources on C:
3. Do a "Get Latest Version" on your workspace, to download the sources from TFS and to update the workspace in TFS
4. Checkout all files in your workspace (checkout root folder with recursive option)
5. Copy your saved code from step 1 into your workspace
6. check in your changes (check in on root folder of workspace again with recursive option)
7. your sources are now linked to and stored in TFS

Under "Tools-> Options-> Source Control -> Environment -> Saving/Editing" set the value to check out automatically, so that VS will to the checkout for you automatically when changing a file in VS.

Comment: This is depressing! I would've imagined TFS to be able to intelligently notice that it's the same ol' project, just with a changed directory..

Comment: How should it know that it is just a changed location and not another Version/release, which is branched? You need to tell TFS what you do and what you want, otherwise it would do things you don't expect.

Comment: @MikeR Git is pretty good about it...